# Using Ajax to pass Json variable and decode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a AJAX script which i was using previously and was able to retrieve data from `viewCommentsJson.php` as such`[{"comments":"Greta"},{"comments":"John"}]`. I was wondering if its able to decode the return value such that it display it properly ?

Thanks in advance

> Greta
>  John

Main.php

```
<a onclick="showUser('.$row['ID'].')" method = "POST" action= "viewCommentsJson.php">Show Comments</a>

 <script>
    function showUser(str) {
      if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      } 
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("Post","viewCommentsJson.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

**viewCommentsJson.php**

```
$com = $_REQUEST["q"];

include 'connectDatabase.php';
//opening sql table
$selected = mysql_select_db("2000",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select 2000");
$arr = array();
$data = mysql_query("SELECT comments FROM comment WHERE ID = '$com'");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't mind a jQuery solution, here is how it can be done

```
function showUser(str) {
      if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      } 
      $.ajax({
          type:'post',
          url: 'viewCommentsJson.php',
          data:{q:str},
          success:function(data)
          {
              data = $.parseJSON(data);
              var response;
              $.each(data, function(index, value){
                   response += value+'<br />';
              });
              $('#txtHint').html(response);
          }
      });
}
```

You can refer [**$.ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [**$.parseJSON**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) for more information.

Note: Your `SELECT comments FROM comment WHERE ID = '$com'` is prone to SQL injection. At the very least, you should sanitize all incoming data before using it in your query directly.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. However i ran into a problem after replacing with your script. `ReferenceError: showUser is not defined`. I do not understand why `showUser` is not defined given that the function is being declared.

Comment: Try putting your `<script>` tag above your `<a onclick.....` tag. Also, an anchor tag shouldn't have `method` and `action` attributes so you can remove them from the `<a>` tag too

Comment: I am sorry i cant add the `<script>` tag above `<a onclick.....` it will render my button invisible. Also i will be needing to pass the value `.$row['ID'].` into `$com = $_REQUEST["q"];`

Comment: Why would it make your button invisible? It won't and it shouldn't

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about encapsulating the `<a onClick...>` with the script tag as such right ? `<script><a onclick="showUser('.$row['ID'].')">Show Comments</a></script>`

Comment: No. I meant `<script>function showUser(str){...}</script><a onclick="showUser('.$row['ID'].')">Show Comments</a>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53954/discussion-between-user2691544-and-asprin)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a onclick="showUser('1')" href="#?">Show Comments</a>

<script>
    function showUser(str) {
      if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      } 
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          data = eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
          for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
             document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML + data[i].comments;
          }          
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("Post","viewCommentsJson.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

First of all remove method and action from A tag and used above code now. Removed some typos

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out. I got an `Uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected identifier error.`Any idea where i might have screw up again ?